# how to check if Observable is empty or returns Boolean value

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

lets say i have observable that call rest api service then store the result in database:

```java
public Observable<Boolean> initDB() {
    return this.restApi.feedsEntityList()
        .flatMap(feedEntityList -> this.mNewsCache.saveFeeds(feedEntityList));
}
```

the save Observable perform the database saving and should return true in case of success or false in case of an error occurred:

```java
public Observable<Boolean> saveFeeds(List<FeedEntity> feedEntity) {
   if (feedEntity != null) {
       return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Boolean>() {
           @Override
           public void call(Subscriber<? super Boolean> subscriber) {
               try {
                   Log.d("DB: ", "saving Feed to DB");
                   for (FeedEntity feeds : feedEntity) {
                       feeds.save();
                   }
                   subscriber.onNext(true);
                   subscriber.onCompleted();
               } catch (Exception exception) {
                   subscriber.onError(exception);
               }
           }
       });
   } else return Observable.empty();
}
```

in this last observable, i am not sure if i am doing it correctly. i.e. return true if database saving operation is done successfully. return false otherwise!

also, should i return feedEntity is null?

is that correct? and how should i check if observable returns true, false or empty Observable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> and how should i check if observable returns true, false [...]

When you subscribe to an `Observable<Boolean>` that emits either true or false, `onNext(Boolean)` will be called with a value of either true or false.

For example:

```
saveFeed(feeds).subscribe(new Action1<Boolean>() {

    @Override
    public void call(Boolean result) {
        // result will be either true or false.
    }

});
```

> how should i check if observable returns [...] empty Observable

[As per the documentation](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Creating-Observables), `Observable.empty()` *emits nothing,* then completes. Your `onNext()` will never be called, but `onComplete()` will be called.

If you *really* wanted to, you could monitor whether `onNext()` is called, and if you `onNext()` isn't called but `onComplete()` is, you know it never emitted anything. This probably isn't really what you want though.

> in this last observable, i am not sure if i am doing it correctly. i.e. return true if database saving operation is done successfully. return false otherwise!

You aren't.

You never call `subscriber.onNext(false)`, so your Observable will never emit `false`. An `Observable<Boolean>` doesn't emit `false` by default- it simply won't emit anything.

Comment: great ... referring to the first Observer.. is it going to be terminated after flatMap transformation? in other world, what will happen in that observer after data saved?

Comment: The function in `flatMap()` will be called every time `onNext()` is called from the first Observable. Once your `saveFeeds()` Observable completes, the entire chain will be complete since that is the last Observable in the chain.